# How to use the sum of two fields when searching for a document in MongoDB?

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

I have a collection of accounts and I am trying to find an account in which the `targetAmount >= totalAmount + N`

```json
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "60d097b761484f6ad65b5305"
  },
  "targetAmount": 100,
  "totalAmount": 0,
  "highPriority": false,
  "lastTimeUsed": 1624283088
}
```

Now I just select all accounts, iterate over them and check if the condition is met. But I'm trying to do this all in a query:

```py
amount = 10

tasks = ProviderAccountTaskModel.objects(
    __raw__={
        'targetAmount': {
            '$gte': {'$add': ['totalAmount', amount]}
        }
    }
).order_by('-highPriority', 'lastTimeUsed')
```

I have also tried using the `$sum`, but both options do not work.
Can't it be used when searching, or am I just going the wrong way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `$where`. Just be aware it will be fairly slow (has to execute Javascript code on every record) so combine with indexed queries if you can.

```
db.getCollection('YourCollectionName').find( { $where: function() { return this.targetAmount > (this.totalAmount + 10) } })
```

or more compact way of doing it will be

```
db.getCollection('YourCollectionName').find( { $where: "this.targetAmount > this.totalAmount +  10" })
```

Comment: Wow, didn't know this is possible till now. Great answer. Where can I learn more about this with examples?

Comment: [$where](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) might be this doc can help you.@hhharsha36

Answer (score 0):

You have to use aggregation instead of the find command since self-referencing of documents in addition to arithmetic operations won't work on it.

Below is the aggregation command you are looking for. Convert it into motoengine equivalent command.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "$expr": {
        "$gte": [
          "$targetAmount",
          {
            "$sum": [
              "$totalAmount",
              10
            ]
          },
        ],
      },
    },
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "highPriority": -1,
      "lastTimeUsed": 1,
    },
  },
])
```

[Mongo Playground Sample Execution](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1-ooS3D87u8)